# .htaccess - RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok I have the following .htaccess and it works however I can seem to change it to the way I need it.

here is the current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|system|images|tpl|js|lib|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?tpl=$1 [L]


Options +FollowSymlinks
```

I need to add the following

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cat=$1&tpl=$2 [L]
```

So i am wondering how do I get that rule to work? as when I add it it does not.

Comment: `[L]` means *last*. Hence if first rewrite works, no other will do for the same request.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add a rule that will handle all requests except the first one that matches the RewriteCond And those would be split into /?

I think something like this would work. Please note that I changed the $1 to ${REQUEST_URI} in your rewrite condition

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|admin|system|images|tpl|js|lib|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?tpl=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)?$ /index.php?cat=$1&tpl=$2 [L]

Options +FollowSymlinks
```